# C# NUnrar library (extracting password protected rar files without password)

Tags: c#, rar, winrar

I am using this library in C# to extract RAR files.

http://nunrar.codeplex.com/

Is it able to extract a file even if it is password protected? It doesn't even ask for password. How is that possible?

*I am creating RAR files using WinRar and putting password on them.*

Comment: Apparently it can't decrypt a file, considering the project's asking for help with "complex items like encryption".

Comment: right, I also saw this comment: http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/discussions/261996

Comment: are you absolutely sure the file is password protected?

Comment: @w0lf
Yes I am 100% sure. And strange thing is if you just password protect ZIP file it is able to unzip it without asking password. But if you also encrypt file names inside ZIP files then it can't unzip it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of nunrar and https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/

I am making decryption of password protected rar archives my next item to do as I thought I had already done it (zip files blurred my memory).

As another comment said, I am always looking for help but hopefully I'll get this done soon.

Comment: Was this implemented?  If so can you show me how to do it?  Many thanks :-)

Comment: Could you please update your answer if support is added (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763951/how-to-extract-files-from-rar-file-having-a-password?noredirect=1 which I linked as dup for this one)

Comment: SharpCompress (NUnrar successor) supports decrypting rar files https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress

Answer (score 1):

(End of Year 2018.) Solution for unpacking RAR (4 or 5 format) archive with Password: 
Install Nuget Packages 7z.Libs (https://www.nuget.org/packages/7z.Libs/) and Squid-Box.SevenZipSharp (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Squid-Box.SevenZipSharp/). 
Using this code: (edit: error correction)

```
        public void Unpack()
        {
            var rawBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(".\\Some.rar");

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(rawBytes, true))
            {
                // Toggle between the x86 and x64 bit dll
                var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86", "7z.dll");
                SevenZip.SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath(path);

                using (var outMemStream = File.Create(".\\SomeSingleFile.txt"))
                {
                    var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(stream, "passwordXXX");
                    var entry = extractor.ArchiveFileData.Single(info => false == info.IsDirectory);    
                    extractor.ExtractFile(entry.Index, outMemStream);                        
                }
            }
        }
```